# I have installed Postgres server 10.7 in ubuntu 16.04 and I am not getting the same version of Postgres client

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

```
psql (9.5.14, server 10.7)
WARNING: psql major version 9.5, server major version 10.Some psql features might not work.
```

Please help me to install Postgres client 10.7.

Answer (score 0):

psql is a local tool that connects to a remote database. The versions not matching isn't necessarily a problem and simply indicate that the PostgreSQL version you have on your machine is not the same as on the server.

To get rid of the warning, you'd have to install the same PostgreSQL version locally. Or you can just ignore it.